# Display 12 columns each for a month but month values dependent on User selected Month

Tags: crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2010, dynamic-columns

**Using Crystal Reports for VS2010.**

I have the following requirement for a standalone CR.:

*From the indicated start date, retrieve all sales records from the table for the next 12 months. StartDate is the parameter that report uses and user selects.*

Columns are as under: 
Month1 is the month of the StartDate followed by consecutive months.

```
Column1     Column2      Month1 Month2 M3  M4  M5  M6  M7  M8  M9  M10 M11  M12
```

For eg: If StartDate is 01/05/2013 (May 2013) then columns should be:

```
Column1     Column2      May13 Jun13 Jul13  Aug13  Sep13  Oct13  Nov13  Dec13  Jan14  Feb14 Mar14  Apr14
```

Would really appreciate if someone could point me to links or give some directions on how to achieve this.

***UPDATE:***

I have managed to achieve the Dynamic column headers using formula

```
ToText(DateAdd('m', 1, {?StartDate}), 'MMM yy')
```

I am stuck figuring out a formula to get the data value in the Detail section. 
If field name is {Sales.Extension} how do I calculate the Sum of Extension for that Month only.

Comment: `For that month` means only the month that user selects in parameter? and not rest of months that are displayed in detail section.

Comment: Nope. Sorry. For that month means the respective month column. One value for each month (12 columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the extent I understand the problem you can use below solution.

1. Create a formula and write below code and place in detail section.

   `If ToText(DateAdd('m', 1, {?StartDate}), 'MMM yy')= ToText(DateAdd('m', 1, <<Database Field>>), 'MMM yy')
   Then {Sales.Extension}`

write above formula for all columns in report.

If you need the summary then take summary of the field placed in detail section.

Comment: Legend. Thats what I exactly did. I was gonna self answer my question, but appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cross-tab; add the sales date to the columns area; group by month.  Add the value to be summarized to the rows area.

Record-selection formula:

```
{table.sales_date} IN {?StartDate} TO DateAdd("m", 12, {?StartDate})
```

Comment: Thanks Craig. I took a different approach. For the header I added formula such as this 
"ToText(DateAdd('m', 1, {?StartDate}), 'MMM yy')" Giving me following 12 months. I am stuck on the actual Detail section data. 
If Field name is Extension, how can I get the sum of Extension for each month?